# How to compare variables to a number in a column (dataframe) in R

Tags: r

I'm really having a hard time getting this exercise done. We're supposed to compare a vector in a data frame (the data frame is called "verbs" in R) to log(5) which is 1.609438(verbs$LengthOfTheme > 5). Using a For-Loop I have been able to complete the task only for the mentioned column. But when I try to use the code for the whole data frame, so that at the end I get the new data frame with the column "LengthOfTheme" containing only the variable which are bigger than 5, I get wrong results. My code is the following:

for the column LengthOfTheme separately:

```
data(verbs)
for (x in verbs$LengthOfTheme) {
  if (x > 1.609438) {
    print(x)
  }
}
```

now the problematic code:

```
data(verbs)
for (x in 1:nrow(verbs)) {
  if (verbs$LengthOfTheme[x] > 1.609438) {
    verbs$LengthOfTheme[x] = x
  }
}
verbs
```

The data frame looks like this:

[The data frame looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrNAH.png)

Comment: Please use ``dput(verbs)`` to show us what the data looks like. Thank you.

Comment: Do you **have** to use `for` loop? I think `new_verb <- verbs[verbs$LengthOfTheme > 1.609438, ]` should give you what you want.

Comment: I just added the data frame to my post. The idea is: the code should loop through the last column "LengthOfTheme", compare the variable stored there to 1.609438, and then print out the same data frame, however only with the variable which are greater than 1.609438. Variable lesser than 1.609438 should be omitted.

Comment: @Klay Given your data frame, what should the final data frame output look like? Or what is expected to be printed in the console if the code is doing what you want?

Comment: @Ben the data frame that should be the output is the same input data frame only with the rows containing the variables (stored in the column LengthOfTheme) which are greater than 1.609438.

Comment: @Klay did you try ronak’s suggestion? This should work for you. Or if it doesn’t give you what you want, please explain. You shouldn’t need a loop for this.

Comment: @Ronak, thank you so much, I tried your suggestion and it worked like it is supposed to be. I appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use a loop. You can subset a data frame directly using a logical test on the specified column. `verbs[verbs$LengthOfTheme > 1.609438,]`